# how to get the item_number in paypal IPN?

Tags: php, paypal

here's a sample response from the paypal after I completed the payment of the cart using the sandbox

```
Array
(
    [address_city] => San Jose
    [address_country] => United States
    [address_country_code] => US
    [address_name] => Test User
    [address_state] => CA
    [address_status] => confirmed
    [address_street] => 1 Main St
    [address_zip] => 95131
    [business] => test_biz@gmail.com
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [custom] => 
    [first_name] => Test
    [form_charset] => UTF-8
    [item_name1] => iPod Touch
    [item_name2] => Giant Hamburger, the world's biggest
    [item_number1] => 2
    [item_number2] => 1
    [last_name] => User
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [mc_fee] => 0.79
    [mc_gross] => 17.00
    [mc_gross_1] => 7.00
    [mc_gross_2] => 10.00
    [mc_handling] => 0.00
    [mc_handling1] => 0.00
    [mc_handling2] => 0.00
    [mc_shipping] => 2.00
    [mc_shipping1] => 2.00
    [mc_shipping2] => 0.00
    [merchant_return_link] => click here
    [notify_version] => 3.4
    [num_cart_items] => 2
    [payer_email] => test_per@gmail.com
    [payer_id] => TRCLJTHLNCJ7Q
    [payer_status] => verified
    [payment_date] => 23:14:45 Jan 02, 2012 PST
    [payment_fee] => 0.79
    [payment_gross] => 17.00
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [payment_type] => instant
    [protection_eligibility] => Eligible
    [quantity1] => 1
    [quantity2] => 1
    [receiver_email] => test_biz@gmail.com
    [receiver_id] => 74PV23B8KSK84
    [residence_country] => US
    [tax] => 0.00
    [tax1] => 0.00
    [tax2] => 0.00
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [transaction_subject] => Shopping CartiPod TouchGiant Hamburger, the world's biggest
    [txn_id] => 4BK63214AG342352Y
    [txn_type] => cart
    [verify_sign] => A0Jk1FY.7aHd-VRk44a4grBP7kE.A0Azn34Obs6QiSJKuCvAWSWyItkH
)
```

as you can see, there's item_name1 and item_name2 how to get the values of these items let's say e.g I have had paid 10 items?. that would be like from item_name1 to item_name10

I generated that numbering of items via my PHP code, like this

```
<?php
  $i = 1;
  foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $qty):
  $product = find_product($id);
?>

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['ProductDescription']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['ProductID']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['ProductOverridePrice']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>">

<?php
  $i++;
  endforeach;
?>
```

and if you look at the sample paypal response, there is mc_gross_1 , mc_gross_2 ...tax1,tax2  and the like ..so how will I get those values of the ones that has incremented numbers and save it in the db ?

Answer (score 5):

You do also have `[num_cart_items] = 2` though.
So just do a loop ...

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['num_cart_items']; $i++) {
   $name = $_POST['item_name' . $i];
   $number = $_POST['item_number' . $i];
   $quantity = $_POST['quantity' . $i];
   //etc...

   $query = "INSERT INTO payments (product_name, product_id, product_quantity)
             VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($number) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($quantity) . "')";
   mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: One small caveat: the `num_cart_items` parameter is not supplied by the PayPal IPN Simulator. Just thought I'd mention that in case someone is using that for testing.

Comment: How to send multiple items in paypal button form

Comment: You use `.` to concatenate in PHP.